# Find the approx. val using the cubic spline

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

This is homework. I need to calculate the derivative of this function found by using the cubic spline bounded.

The original approx is used to calculate sin, the question asked is $cos 0.34$

$S(x) = 0.31457 + 0.71244(x-0.32) + 15.6149(x-0.32)^2 - 262.80741(x-0.32)^3$

so I thought about plugging in $S'(0.34)$ to find $cos 0.34$
This didn't work.

I have all the values of the derivatives for the original equation. I could construct a new cubic spline for cos but this is just inefficient. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Just use $\cos(0.34)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(0.34)}$

Comment: Thanks this works great, exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: This functionality would probably only work with problems involving things like trig identities